# ReactJS - Main.js eror 4040

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have a pwa built in ReactJS and every time I upload a new version to the server it gives error 404 in the main.js file and I have to refresh the page (CTRL + F5) so that the content is displayed. Does anyone have a tip on how to prevent this?
[image]

Comment: You're browser is caching the page. Change the browser settings. The last thing you want is to be able to control peoples browser settings when they come to your page.

Comment: But I need to check this in the application. I can't change the browser settings of all users

Comment: Excatly, you can't, so they all have to change the browser settings themselves. When the browser notices a lot of initial script processing running it caches a lot of things. Have it as a requirement to cache the page in the browser.